# Is there a way to implicitly set properties in constructor in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Imagine a simple class with a basic constructor:

```
class Animal {
    name: string
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

The problem about this is somewhat obvious: with a growing number of properties (`age: number; type: AnimalType` etc) one has to write those things thrice:

```
class Animal {
    name: string
    age: number
    type: AnimalType
    // ...
    constructor(name: string, age: number, type: AnimalType) {
        this.name = name
        this.age = age
        this.type = type
        // ...
    }
}
```

so the `constructor` will get bigger and bigger, and the code is not particularly DRY. Is there some standart way to avoid this in TS? I can imagine something like

```
class Animal {
    @Required name: string
    @Required age: number
    @Required type: AnimalType
    // ...
    constructor(anotherParam) {
        // implicitly: this.name = name
        // implicitly: this.age = age
        // implicitly: this.type = type

        // deal with anotherParam
    }
}
```

but the syntax is not accurate, rather to illustrate the expected result.

The only simple solution that I'm aware of is to create an interface like this:

```
interface AnimalPermanentParams {
    name: string
    age: number
    type: AnimalType
}

class Animal {
    permanentParams: AnimalPermanentParams
    // ...
    constructor(permanentParams: AnimalPermanentParams, anotherParam) {
        this.permanentParams = permanentParams
        // ...
    }
}
```

but this has an obvious drawback of an extra layer: we have to use `this.permanentParams.age` instead of just `this.age`. So are there any sane alternatives?

Comment: `this is somewhat basic question` Apparently not since I'm also not finding a duplicate on SO after searching for 5 minutes :)

Comment: @MikeS. well, hope somebody finds it helpful, too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just declare the parameter as `public` (or `private`) and it will set the property for you.

```
class Animal {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}


new Animal("abc").name
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeAoavrAHt4IAXAJwFdgSCyAKABwoCMRFhp4xkBTALmikyieAHMAlJgC+WGVng8A7nCSoQdAERhmwDeIB0XXkA)

Comment: Or `private` to a similar effect for private properties. That's a very common pattern for dependency injection.

Comment: @Alejandro yeap, exactly, used with `private` already (SO doesn't allow to accept just yet). Have seen this pattern back when used Angular (exactly for dependency injection), but forgot about it